# Import CSV in excel by applying delimiter and format it as table with a certain name

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have a CSV with values with the format:`123;456;789;` for over 80k rows.
I want to **import the data into an excel sheet, apply delimiter, format the data as a table and give the table a name**.

I have tried parsing the data line by line, but I realised this is a very slow way to do it. It takes over 15 minutes to finish the process.

My original code below (directory is the location of CSV that I need to import, and only 1 file will be imported, so new solution doesn't need to take into account the case of several files):

```
Private Sub ReloadTable (directory As String, filter As String, tableRange As Range)
    Dim file        As Variant
    Dim lines       As Collection
    Dim itemArray () As String
    Dim newrow      As ListRow
    Dim i, j, progressStep As Integer
    
    Application. DisplayStatusBar = TRUE
    Application. ScreenUpdating = FALSE
    Application. Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    With tableRange.ListObject
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            .DataBodyRange.Delete
        End If
        
        For Each file In GetAllFiles (directory, filter)
            Set lines = GetLinuxLine (directory & file)
            progressStep-WorkshgetFunction.Max(1,WorksheetFunctio.Min(300, Int (lines.Count / 100) ))
            For i =1 To lines.Count
                If i Mod progressStep = 0 Then
                    Application. StatusBar =  "Importing & directory & file & " (" & CStr (i) & "/m & CStr (lines. Count) & ") "
                    DoEvents
                End If
                
                itemArray = Split (lines.Item (i),"; ",-1,vbTextCompare)
                Set newrow = ListRows.Add
                With newrow
                    For j = 1 To .Range.Count
                        .Range (j) = itemArray (j - 1)
                    Next j
                End With
            Next i
        Next file
    End With
    
    Application. StatusBar= ""
    Application. Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application. ScreenUpdating = TRUE
End Sub
```

My thought on improving this code is that, instead of performing operation line by line,  I plan to:

1. Apply delimiter on the CSV & open a worksheet of the CSV with delimiter applied
2. Copy all data
3. Paste them in the destination worksheet
4. Format it as a table and name it as "tCSV"

I made some code to try it out, but seems like I failed to apply delimiter (as the wb result does not have delimiter applied):

```
csv_file= "S:\aaaa\ABC.csv"
Set wb = Workbooks. Open (csv_file, Format: =6, Delimiter:=";")

tt = wb, Sheets (1) . Range ("A1") .Value

MsgBox tt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CSV To New Excel Table (`ListObjbect`)

**The Main Procedure**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values from a CSV file in a new table
'               in a worksheet of the workbook containing this code.
' Calls:        TextFileToArray
'               GetSplitArray
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub ImportCSV()
    Const ProcName As String = "ImportCSV"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
      
    Const SRC_FILE_PATH  As String = "C:\Test\Test.csv"
    Const DST_WORKSHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const DST_TABLE_NAME As String = "tCSV"
    
    Dim sArr As Variant: sArr = TextFileToArray(SRC_FILE_PATH, vbCrLf)
    If IsEmpty(sArr) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dData As Variant: dData = GetSplitArray(sArr, ";")
    If IsEmpty(dData) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_WORKSHEET_NAME)
    Dim dfcell As Range: Set dfcell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = dfcell.Resize(UBound(dData, 1), UBound(dData, 2))
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    drg.Value = dData
    dws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, drg, , xlYes).Name = DST_TABLE_NAME
    drg.Columns.AutoFit
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "CSV file imported.", vbInformation

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "@" & ProcName & "@ Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

**The 1st Helper Function**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns each line of a text file in an element
'               of a 1D zero-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function TextFileToArray( _
    ByVal FilePath As String, _
    Optional LineSeparator As String = vbLf) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "TextFileToArray"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim TextFile As Long: TextFile = FreeFile
    
    Dim sArr() As String
    
    Open FilePath For Input Access Read As TextFile
        On Error Resume Next
            sArr = Split(Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile), LineSeparator)
        On Error GoTo ClearError
    Close TextFile

    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = UBound(sArr) To LBound(sArr) Step -1
        If Len(sArr(n)) > 0 Then Exit For
    Next n
    
    If n < LBound(sArr) Then Exit Function
    If n < UBound(sArr) Then ReDim Preserve sArr(0 To n)
    
    TextFileToArray = sArr

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "@" & ProcName & "@ Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

**The 2nd Helper Function**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the split substrings of each element of a 1D array
'               in columns of a row of a 2D one-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetSplitArray( _
    ByVal SourceArray As Variant, _
    Optional Delimiter As String = ",") _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "GetSplitArray"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim cLB As Long: cLB = LBound(SourceArray)
    Dim cUB As Long: cUB = UBound(SourceArray)
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = cUB - cLB + 1
    If drCount = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    Dim nArr() As String, nUB As Long, n As Long, c As Long
    Dim Data() As Variant, dr As Long, dcCount As Long
    
    For c = cLB To cUB
        dr = dr + 1
        nArr = Split(SourceArray(c), Delimiter)
        nUB = UBound(nArr)
        If c = cLB Then ' first
            dcCount = nUB + 1
            ReDim Data(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
        Else ' all but first
            If nUB >= dcCount Then
                dcCount = nUB + 1
                ReDim Preserve Data(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
            End If
        End If
        For n = 0 To nUB
            Data(dr, n + 1) = nArr(n)
        Next n
    Next c

    GetSplitArray = Data

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "@" & ProcName & "@ Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

1. if you are on excel newer than 2010* the above scenario is a good reason to learn powerquery (get and transform) instead of VBA. It does exactly what you want to happen and it does so multithreaded by default.
2. to fix the performance of you code as is, i would recommend batching your write operations to the sheet, i.e instead of doing

   ```
            With newrow
                For j = 1 To .Range.Count
                    .Range (j) = itemArray (j - 1)
                Next j
   ```

   do something like

   dim out(1 to 100, 1 to 256) as variant #or whatever number of columns you expect to have

   [loop through 100 rows of your file and split them into the out array]

   sheet.range(sheet.cell(startrow, 1), sheet.cell(startrow+100, 256).value=out
3. to get excel to open and parse a csv file with correct delimiter use Workbooks.OpenText instead of Workbooks.Open

*https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/power-query-version-compatibility-and-installation